# Не удаётся подключиться к MongoDB через Hibernate OGM используя sessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, mongodb

Разрабатываю приложение, использующее Hibernate OGM для работы с MongoDB. Для подключения используется sessionFactory (это обязательно), столкнулся с ошибкой при конфигурации. Лог:

```
...
2020-12-21 11:09:06 INFO  DatastoreProviderInitiator:51 - OGM000016: NoSQL Datastore provider: org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider
2020-12-21 11:09:06 ERROR HibernateDataProvider:108 - org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: OGM000072: Unable to configure datastore provider
```

Класс HibernateUtil для получения sessionFactory:

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.ogm.cfg.OgmConfiguration;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            Configuration configuration = new OgmConfiguration();
            //assuming the default mongodb settings
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider",
                    "MONGODB");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host",
                    "127.0.0.1");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port",
                    "27017");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.ogm.mongodb.database",
                    "test");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.ogm.datastore.create__database",
                    "true");
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

How to fix this problem?